# Regular expression capturing entire match consisting of repeated groups

Tags: python, regex

I've looked thrould the forums but could not find exactly how exactly to solve my problem.

Let's say I have a string like the following:

```
UDK .636.32/38.082.4454.2(575.3)
```

and I would like to match the expression with a regex, capturing the actual number (in this case the '.636.32/38.082.4454.2(575.3)').

There could be some garbage characters between the 'UDK' and the actual number, and characters like '.', '/' or '-' are valid parts of the number. Essentially the number is a sequence of digits separated by some allowed characters.

What I've came up with is the following regex:

```
'UDK.*(\d{1,3}[\.\,\(\)\[\]\=\'\:\"\+/\-]{0,3})+'
```

but it does not group the '.636.32/38.082.4454.2(575.3)'! It leaves me with nothing more than a last digit of the last group (3 in this case).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

First, you need a non-greedy `.*?`.
Second, you don't need to escape some chars in `[ ]`.
Third, you might just consider it as a sequence of digits AND some allowed characters? Why there is a `\d{1,3}` but a `4454`?

```
>>> re.match(r'UDK.*?([\d.,()\[\]=\':"+/-]+)', s).group(1)
'.636.32/38.082.4454.2(575.3)'
```

Comment: The question is still not really clear, but I suggest you add anchors: `^UDK.*?([\d.,()\[\]=\':"+/-]+)$`.  In other words, the "number" is the *last* bunch of eligible characters; if some of those characters also appear among the "garbage character" in the middle, it won't confuse the regex.

Comment: I'm sorry, that's a mistake with the four-digit group - it should also be included. The idea is that there MUST be 1 to 4 digits which MIGHT be followed with one or more of the allowed separators like dots or dashes. Probably @eph's answer solves the problem, however I'm not sure as string like "...." or "12345/12345" would be also OK, but it shouldn't be.

Comment: @artonson what does "MIGHT" mean? If it means separators can be omitted, the length of digits could be infinite.

Comment: @artonson An appropriate regex fits what it is used for rather than what it really is. Do you want to restrict the input or just extract from what you are quite sure there is no things like `12345`? The former needs more details, such as whether the group can/must/never start/end with non-digits, whether `UDK` is the start of string/line or follows some letters, what exactly could be before/after main group, which group in `UDK 123 456` should be captured. You might get a large and slow regex at the end, while for the later one, it can be simple and fast. Maybe just as simple as `UDK\s+(\S+)`.

Comment: If there is more then one group of digits, separators cannot be omitted. If only one, there can be no separators.

Comment: @artonson As an example, `^UDK +([.,()\[\]=\':"+/-]*(\d{1,4}[.,()\[\]=\':"+/-]+)*\d{1,4}[.,()\[\]=\':"+/-]*)$` matches a string that starts with UDK, followed by one or more white spaces, then the main group for all remaining string, which contains one or more digits groups of length 1~4, separated by some allowed characters, which could also be at the start or end of main group.

Answer (score 0):

Not so much a direct answer to your problem, but a general regexp tip: use Kodos (http://kodos.sourceforge.net/).  It is simply *awesome* for composing/testing out regexps.  You can enter some sample text, and "try out" regular expressions against it, seeing what matches, groups, etc.  It even generates Python code when you're done.  Good stuff.

Edit: using Kodos I came up with:

```
UDK.*?(?P<number>[\d/.)(]+)
```

as a regexp which matches the given example.  Code that Kodos produces is:

```
import re

rawstr = r"""UDK.*?(?P<number>[\d/.)(]+)"""
matchstr = """UDK .636.32/38.082.4454.2(575.3)"""

# method 1: using a compile object
compile_obj = re.compile(rawstr)
match_obj = compile_obj.search(matchstr)

# Retrieve group(s) by name
number = match_obj.group('number')
```